# Delete repeated subdirectory of url with redirect 301 in Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, redirect

I have to delete a subdirectory that has been duplicated in several URLs of my site, through a permanent redirect 301.

I'm needing help with the Nginx configuration.

For example:
`http://example.com/foo/DIR/DIR/bar` --> `http://example.com/foo/DIR/bar`

```
location ~ ^(.*)/DIR/DIR(.*)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /DIR/$1 last;
    break;
}
```

My current nginx server configuration:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl http2 fastopen=500 reuseport;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 fastopen=500 reuseport ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.example.com;
    resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 valid=300s;

    charset utf-8;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/diffie-hellman;

    root /var/www/webdisk/example.com/htdocs;

    autoindex off;
    index load.php index.php index.html;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/security;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/expires;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/error_pages;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/pagespeed;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 1200s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1200s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 75s;
    }

# TODO: http://example.com/foo/DIR/DIR/bar --> http://example.com/foo/DIR/bar

    location ~* ^/(.+)$ {
        if (-f $document_root/public/prov/$1.html) {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /public/prov/$1.html last;
            break;
        }
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /load.php?request=$1 last;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

I hope you can help me, to understand how this kind of redirection should be done.

P.S.
After the redirection, it must be processed under the latest directive towards the PHP Framework. `/load.php?request=$1`

Thank you.

Comment: Try this (it does not need to be wrapped inside a `location` block): `rewrite ^(.*)/DIR/DIR(.*)$ $1/DIR$2 permanent;`

Comment: @RichardSmith
It worked, I preferred to add it inside the "location" block. It was useful thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect with a 301 response, you need to use `rewrite...permanent` or `return 301 ...`.

To remove part of a URI, you need to capture those parts of the URI both before and after the part to be removed - much like the regular expression in your `location` statement.

For example:

```
rewrite ^(.*)/DIR/DIR(.*)$ $1/DIR$2 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.